# Error: pymongo.errors.WriteError: '$set' is empty

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I m trying to update a docs field using pymongo as below:

```
query = {"node_name": "1"}
set_docs = {"$set": {'shipped_date': 'N/A', 'support_end_date': 'N/A'}
mongodb.update(query, {"$set": set_docs}, upsert=False}
```

The above command throwing error:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: '$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}
```

Is it possible to use the dict object, instead of key: value in $set.

Comment: why do you've `$set` again in `mongodb.update(query, {"$set": set_docs}, upsert=False})` ? as your `set_docs ` has already included it !! you might need to try `mongodb.update(query, set_docs, upsert=False})` , if `node_name` is unique you can try `mongodb.update_one(query, set_docs, upsert=False})`

Answer (score 2):

Code error:

```
set_docs = {"$set": {'shipped_date': 'N/A', 'support_end_date': 'N/A'}}
mongodb.update(query, set_docs, upsert=False}
```